# Dotless Could not load file or assembly dotless.aspnet

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, dotless

I am having problem in getting .less file compiled using dotless in visual studio 2017. I have installed the the dotless pakcage 1.6.7. I get the following error.

Could not load file or assembly 'dotless.AspNet' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Can anybody please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled the 1.6.7 package and installed 1.5.2 and it started working.